# How can i make all variables outiside accessible inside a method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, variables, methods, scope

I undestand that would be considered a bad practice but my purpose is just for study, i wanna undestand if a function "render" with a include inside, can have this include to have access to outside variables or it will lose it anyway, even because that render is already the end of the application so wouldn't make sense to lose access to those variables and it's annoyng to pass it through the method then use a extract.

I tried using global but you need to inform the name of each variable, and wouldn't work on a greater scale.

**Edit 1:**
I'm adding a little more of informations (sorry it is my first question on stackoverflow)
so the code i was studying was from [league/plates](https://packagist.org/packages/league/plates) i was trying to do what i said above, but i found this snippet of code

```
public function render($data) {
  extract($data);
  ob_start();

  include $this->path();

  $content = ob_get_clean();

  if (isset($this->layoutName)) {
    $layout = $this->engine->make($this->layoutName);
    $layout->sections = array_merge($this->sections, array('content' => $content));
    $content = $layout->render($this->layoutData);
  }

  return $content;
}
```

So, in this code when the view is included all variables that were created before the call of render (inside a controller for example or anything like that) they can't be accessed from inside the view, of course i could pass then through the variable $data, but imagine if i had lots of variables and called render many times it wouldn't make much sense in my opinion. I thought maybe creating a functional facade of the render method but i don't if it's possible and how it would be done.

Comment: A function can access other functions that are outside of the function, typically you should include the file before declaring the function, so that the function you're writing has access to everything you included. It would be unorthodox to have an `include` or `require` within a function.

Comment: If you want something available outside a function where it was created, the easiest thing is to return it from the function. If there are multiple variables, return them in an associative array.  Does that help? The description of the situation was a bit unclear in places, some sample (pseudo-)code would be beneficial to give an example of what you mean.

Comment: Or maybe whatever is in your include should actually be a function itself or something. I feel like there's probably a design mistake somewhere.